# OnClick function starting at opening page

Tags: javascript

This may sound stupid but i wrote some code to convert binary into a normal number. I have a button that you have to press which runs the entire function. However, without clicking the button the function launched.

```
let button = document.getElementById("submit");
let binary;
let result = document.createElement("h1");
result.className = "answer";

button.addEventListener("click", calc());


function calc(){
    binary = document.getElementById("binary").value;
    result.textContent = "The Result is: " + parseInt(binary, 2);
    document.body.appendChild(result);
    console.log('here');
}
```

When i load the page the 'The result is' text is already there and when i do click it it wont console log or change the value.
This may be stupid but i cant figure it out
thanks in advance.

Comment: It should just be `button.addEventListener("click", calc);` The second argument of `addEventListener` should be a FUNCTION, not a function call

Comment: You are calling your function in your listener, the listener expects a reference to that function and not the result. `("click", calc)`

Comment: im used to c++ so u have to put the brackets everytime you write the function down

Comment: Also if you have a form, use the submit event instead of the button click event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This :

```js
let button = document.getElementById("submit");
let binary;
let result = document.createElement("h1");
result.className = "answer";

button.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
  calc();
});


function calc(){
    binary = 1000101; // get binary
    result.textContent = "The Result is: " + parseInt(binary, 2);
    document.body.appendChild(result);
    console.log('here');
}
```

```html
<button id ="submit">
 Submit
</button>
<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue I saw from your code is that you called the function `calc()` in the addEventListener method, instead, you should write it like this `button.addEventListener("click", calc);`, you should pass `calc` and not `calc()`.

Comment: This is the correct answer, the second argument of an event listener has to be a function or a reference to a function, not a call to the function (which will execute immediately by virtue of the invoke operator `()`)